# Running rails server in a Vagrant box with Rubymine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, vagrant, rubymine

I have a vagrant box where I have a rails app running. I can connect to it fine from a terminal and there's no issue launching the server inside the vagrant box.

I'm trying to now use Rubymine to connect to it so I can use its debug capabilities. I've gone through the docs and I've added a remote ruby SDK and pointed to the ruby interpreter inside the vagrant box. The problem is that when I do that, Rubymine tries to connect to 127.0.0.1, but it never manages to. It doesn't throw any error or anything, it just gets stuck.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this to work?

EDIT: corrected IP typo

Comment: why `127.0.0.2` ? is it a typo ? it should connect to 127.0.0.1 associated to the port - how do you start your rails app ? can you access the app from your host

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo, yes. I'll edit it right away.
I can definitely access the app from my host machine, if I start rails inside the box via "rails s -b 0.0.0.0" it works just fine and I can access it on localhost:3000 in the browser. 
It seems RubyMine is also able to connect to the box as when I'm configuring the remote SDK I can successfully test the connection. It's only after I select the SDK and it tried to connect again that it gets stuck...

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the correct port mappings in your Vagrant file, as described [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html) ?

If you haven't, that would be the reason you can't get a connection.  I'm not sure offhand what port the debugger would use; presumably you could configure this as part of the Rails application's startup configuration.

Comment: Yeah, I think I've forwarded all the ports I need, basically just 3000 to 3000 and 1236 to 1236. Other than that, there+s the default mapping of port 22 to 2222